# Does fsspec support virtual filesystems such as pyfileysystem

Tags: python, fsspec, pyfilesystem

One of pyfilesystem's main feature is virtual filesystems. E.g.

```
home_fs = open_fs('~/')
projects_fs = home_fs.opendir('/projects')
```

I think that is a great feature and was hoping that fsspec has something similar. But I couldn't find an example and I'm not able to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want [`DirFileSystem`](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.implementations.dirfs.DirFileSystem), invoked like

```
fs = fsspec.implementations.dirfs.DirFileSystem(
    "<root path>", fs=fsspec.filesystem("file")
)
```

You can apply this to any filesystem, not only local. `root_path` needs to be a string that, when you affix further path parts to it, makes a complete path the target filesystem can understand; it may include the protocol (e.g., for HTTP, it *must* do). In your case, it would be "~" (or the expanded version of this, which would be more explicit).

Alternatively, you can create an arbitrarily mapped virtual filesystem with
[`ReferenceFileSystem`](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.implementations.reference.ReferenceFileSystem).

```
mapping = {"/key1": ["/local/path/file1"],
           "/key2": ["/other/unrelated/path/file"]}
fs = fsspec.filesystem("reference", fo=mapping)
```

Here, fs.cat("/key1") would get the contents of "/local/path/file1". You can have those paths be remote, or a mix of different backends, and even byte ranges of target files.

Comment: Regarding the DirFileSystem example, and after reading the docs, I don't yet understand the 'fs' parameter. Does it need to match the protocol in "<root path>"? Is it always "file"? Or is "<root path>" something special, like the path without any protocol?

Comment: Edited with what I hope is clarification. You are welcome to propose improvements to the class documentation.